# Symbols created in different calls are considered equal by TypeScript

Tags: typescript, symbols

Quite unexpectedly, TS allows this assignment even though the objects don't have the same keys. Is this a bug or intended (e.g. design limitation)? Is there a workaround for TS to understand that each call to `foo` creates a value of a new unique type?

```
function foo(arg: any) {
  const u = Symbol();
  return { [u]: arg };
}

let foo1 = foo(1);
let foo2 = foo("a");

foo1 = foo2;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgUDMCuA7AxjASwmznQggAoBDKAcwC44rsBPASkRTjl2IGd4mOAF44AZRYBbAEYQANhTYBuLnCjAYmKCQRwA2pgC6jGrThIVqFHI2lyARhF3K95ddtkIAJieeKAIip-NwwHX3IvJSA)

update: Interestingly, if the file isn't a module, the `foo` function declaration yields an error: `Return type of exported function has or is using private name 'u'.(4060)`. I wonder why it matters in this case if the file is a module.

Update 2: found https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37469
But I'd still like to know if a workaround exists.

Comment: I don't think it is possible _as-is_ at the moment, because this would require differentiating (on a type level) results of each function call, and AFAIK [there is no such mechanism in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40106#issuecomment-677741032) (at least, for symbols).

Comment: If you are willing to change the invocation code, perhaps there is a way to work around the problem using [nominal typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/nominal-typing)